# MS Project : how to GET a value set with the TimescaleEdit method?

Tags: vba, ms-project

The `TimescaleEdit` method allow to set parameters such as the level of zoom for example:

```
TimescaleEdit Enlarge := TheValue
```

But what instruction (and which syntax) should be used to GET the value set ?

Thanks for your help.

I tried in the immediate window, different codes but none of them is operating, returning various erros.
I'm expecting a numeric value.

Comment: FloMSD, Unfortunately like a lot of parameters in Project, you can set the timescale with VBA but you can't "read" what is set. Sometimes it is possible to deduct what is set via an indirect method but I'd have to know more details on exactly what you are after to determine if that is possible.

Comment: Hi John. My idea was :
- to "read" the zoom value. For example value = 100. 
- Then My VBA code would make value = value + 10  (or -10) using  the method TimescaleEdit Enlarge:= value, ... and all the other paramaters of the method) 

Thanks to this code, I could easily in one or multiple clicks on the macro, zoom or unzoom WITHOUT loosing my display (for example Minorscale =  Days, Major = Weeks and Top = Months). I tried to save displays but the display is easily loosed and the only efficient way I found to maintain it is using the TimescaleEdit method..

I hope this is clear..

Comment: FloMSD. Okay I see your issue. The Zoom group on the View ribbon tab is not the same as the Enlarge argument in the TimeScaleEdit Method. The default Enlarge value is 100% and the TimeScaleEdit method can increase or decrease that value but I'm afraid you won't be able to "read" the current value of the Enlarge argument

Comment: John, thanks for having tried.  I have another solution, not as smart as I would like but it works. I will calculate how many days are displayed (timescalefinish - timescalestart) and look the level of zoom of the timescale (right click on the scale). I do it a couple of time, when setting different zooms with the right click. It's a sort of calibration and I will obtain a relation : Zoom = a * exp(-b), easy to calculate with Excel. Then I know what enlarge value I have to set with the TimescaleEdit method, knowing how many days I want on the display....

Comment: FloMSD. Looks like you found an indirect method to get what you want so give yourself credit.